# How do I refer to a php variable in jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, dialog, window

I'm a complete beginner with jQuery and I have this bit of script here and I want to mix jQuery with PHP. I have Courses and in those Courses are Lessons. A Teacher is assigned to teach a Course. What I want is a link where if I press it a popup appears and in it shows the Lesson details or Course details. My problem is that I will be having multiple links and thus dialogs/modal windows in a page such that $l['id'] and $c['id'] will be different. How can I therefore use $l['id'] and $c['id'] in or with jQuery given that the jQuery script is inside the view file and I'm creating the actual content itself in the controller and passing it onto view. Sorry if I don't make sense cause I'm still quite confused about all this myself.

```
view.php
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
        // setup ul.tabs to work as tabs for each div directly under div.panes
        $("#tabs").tabs();   
        $('#dialog').dialog({   
                             modal: true
                            });          
})
</script>
<h1>Student Hub: Courses for <?php echo $studentName;?></h1>

<div id="tabs">
    <?php echo $content;?>
</div>



controller.php  
This is in a foreach loop
<div class="lessonDetails">
    <p><a href="#lessonInfo'.$l['id'].'">Lesson Details:</a><p>
    <div id="lessonDialog'.$l['id'].'" title="Lesson Details">
    '.$l['name'].'
    </div>
</div>  

<div class="courseDetails">
    <p><a href="#courseInfo'.$c['id'].'">Course Timetable & Resources</a><p>
    <div id="courseDialog'.$c['id'].'" title="Course Details">
    <p>'.$c['fullname'].'</p>
    <p>'.$c['summary'].'</p>
    <p>Upcoming Lessons: </p>
</div>
```

Comment: The PHP code should be inside `<?php` and `?>`. Like this: `<?php echo $1['id'] ?>`

Comment: not clear exactly what goes in dialog, ID's will not be critical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technical answer is you don't as one is a server-side language and one is a client-side language; you can't access PHP variables via JavaScript (jQuery). You can, however, drop your PHP variables into your HTML page on generation, and then pick them up with JavaScript or jQuery.

Reading your scenario, I think your over-complicating things. Think of your application; don't think of the technical aspects, but more the way it should be laid out. I'm guessing you have a students controller, a lessons controller, and a courses controller. Those controllers will have actions, called `view` or similar, and then these actions will take an ID to display a particular student/course/lesson.

In your HTML page/view/template, you should have just vanilla URLs. JavaScript should then be used to *enhance* the website. So in your case, I would have mark-up it up similar to as follows:

```
<ul class="courses">
<?php foreach ($courses as $course): ?>
  <li><a href="/courses/view/<?php echo $course->id; ?>"><?php echo $course->title; ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

I'd then, in an external JavaScript file, have a function that listens for a click on the `<a>` tag and instead of navigating to that URL, instead displays the page content in a pop-up/modal window.

```
<script>
    $('.courses a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // load external page and display it in a modal
    });
</script>
```

This way, if for some reason JavaScript's not available then the user will be taken to the course details page. If they do have JavaScript, then they'll get a fancy modal pop-up.

Hope this helps. If you need anything clearing up then let me know, as I have wrote this in the early hours after a few JD and Cokes!

Comment: Hey mate, noticed you're from newcastle. So am I!

Comment: Thanks, so are you saying that I don't need the $l['id'] in the <a> tag? and that I should just use class="lessonDetails" instead and have the jQuery listen out for ALL the <a> tags with the class="lessonDetails". 

If so, then should I not just name ALL the <a> tags that I want as a dialog with class="dialogLink" instead of making it more unique regardless of course or lesson? Then have a div for the dialog's content with a generic attribute again class="dialogContent". Would jQuery find ALL of these and make them ALL dialogs?

<a href="#lessonInfo'.$l['id'].'">Lesson Details:</a>

Answer (score 0):

you can create in every link some extra attributes and using jQuery retrieve the information with the attr function $('a').attr('courses').

somethig  like

```
<a href="#" class=".information" teacher="idTeacher" course="idCourse" >list </a>
```

then using jquery

```
$('.information').click(function(){
teacher= $(this).attr('teacher');
course=$(this).attr('course');



});
```

remember to use $('.information').live() if you are using some AJAX to get the data from the server and the parse it to create the links

Comment: live() is deprecated in jQuery as of 1.7..see API

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create forms that have hidden values in it.

```
<?php foreach($lesson as $l): ?>
  <form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="lesson_id" value="<?php echo $l['id']; ?>" />  
    <a href="#" class="model_window">Click</a>
  </form>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.modal_window').click(function() {
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    var lesson_id = $(form).find('input[name=lesson_id]').val();

    // Do something with lesson_id
  });
});
```

The idea is the same for courses.

********** Edit ****************

Maybe you can try using input arrays. Assumming you have something like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="courses[]" value="1" />  
<input type="hidden" name="courses[]" value="2" />
```

javascript:

```
var courses = $(form).find('input[name^=courses]');
$(courses).each(function() {
  var course = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: I like the idea but I have many Students and each Student is assigned to different courses and thus lessons. Each course contains a different number of lessons so I don't know how many lessons or courses I have which is why I'm iterating in a foreach loop, basically to retrieve all the courses and lessons for a given student. 

Saying that, how would I implement this approach with that in mind? How would I tell jQuery how many times to retrieve values in html markup (which is provided by controller.php)?

Comment: I'm not sure if understand fully, but I added an edit to show how to retrieve input arrays using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can place  tags within your JavaScript code.  Since that code is server side, it will "render" to your JavaScript client side code.  So your JavaScript can access values stored by your PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using jQueryUI dialog. No ID's are required however should they be needed add them as a data attribute to that links

```
<p><a href="#courseInfo'.$c['id'].'" data-id="'.$c['id'].'" >Course Timetable & Resources</a><p>
```

This allows easily getting ID with jQuery data() method.

Dialog is created and destroyed each use. As noted in comments, no idea what content goes in dialog. I can easily adjust if it is ajax from href

```
$('.lessonDetails a, .courseDetails a').click(function(){
    var $this=$(this);
    /* if need the id associated to link*/
    var id=$this.data('id');    

    var content= ''/* ???????   */  

    var title=$this.parent().next().attr('title')
    loadDialog(title, content);
    return false; /* stop browser following href*/

})


function loadDialog(title, content) {

    var dialogOpts = {
        modal: true,
        title: title,
        width: 800,
        close: function() {
            /* remove this dialog from DOM on close*/
            $(this).remove()
        }
    };
    $('<div>').append(content).dialog(dialogOpts);  

}
```

Comment: Hey, I guess id's won't be needed. All I want is multiple dialogs but I don't know how many dialogs because it depends on what student it is and I didn't know how jQuery would keep track of the amount of dialogs that need to be made. Beginner jQuery-er ---->

I don't think content will be used in jQuery as it'll just be done on from the controller. It'll be something like this:
  <div id="courseDialog'.$c['id'].'" title="Course Details">
    <p>'.$c['fullname'].'</p>
    <p>'.$c['summary'].'</p>
    <p>Upcoming Lessons: $upcomingLessons</p>
</div>

Comment: as you can see, dialogs can be created and destroyed on the fly. You still never answered about content..assume is ajax load from php? href's aren't set to a url is why I'm confused

Comment: hrefs aren't set as urls because they're something to click on so a popup window appears

Comment: OK..I thought so, so all you will need to do is steer my content variable to whatever elemnt holds the dialog content using $(selector).html() if it's the ID associated with href is really easy to create selector